# Conditions in Sumproduct if VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have written the following code in VBA and I get a Type Mismatch error in the conditions of the ;SUMPRODUCT;.

```
For Day = 1 To DaysTill
    For m = 0 To Rot
        For n = 0 To StepsNumber
            RArray((Day - 1) * (Rot + 1) + m, n) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(--(Range("HT12:HT1048576") <= RotArray((Day - 1) * (Rot + 1) + m)), --(Range("HS12:HS1048576")) = Day, Range("HT12:HT1048576"), Range("HV12:HV1048576").Offset(, n)) * PriceStepArray(n)
        Next n
    Next m
Next Day
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: When you call the worksheet function from VBA you must supply the parameters in precisely the sequence and formats required. VBA can't just take a string which looks somewhat like the way you might enter the same function in a worksheet. For example, "--" is a very complicated process of multiplications with -1 which VBA definitely doesn't understand. Bear in mind that SUMPRODUCT is a function designed for the worksheet. I recommend that you use it on worksheets. When employing VBA you should make use of VBA's strengths which lies in UDFs.

Comment: @variatus. I understand but with Direct SUMPRODUCT function I hope I would get faster results

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SUMPRODUCT Formula in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042040/sumproduct-formula-in-vba)