# SUMPRODUCT Formula in VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want to use following `SUMPRODUCT` formula in VBA:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sale!$J$5:$J$1048576=C12)*Sale!$D$5:$D$1048576,Sale!$M$5:$M$1048576)
```

I used this code but it gives an error

> Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

```
Dim slWks As Worksheet

Set slWks = Sheets("Sale")
ActiveSheet.Range("F12").Value = _
Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct((slWks.Range("J5:J1048576") = _
    ActiveSheet.Range("C12")) * slWks.Range("D5:D1048576"), slWks.Range("M5:M1048576"))
```

How can I write that formula with its values using vba?

Comment: You can't compare a multi-cell range to one value using `=` in VBA. (the error is actually nothing to do with Sumproduct). Either use an `Evaluate` call to evaluate the formula, or put the formula in the cell and replace it with its value, or use a bridging function to return the array you need.

Comment: Try ActiveSheet.Range("F12").Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT((Sale!$J$5:$J$1048576=C12)*Sale!$D$5:$D$1048576,Sale!$M$5:$M$1048576)"

Comment: Actually, ignore the last part - the resulting array would be too big to use with a worksheet function.

Comment: @Rory is correct, the error is with this bit `(slWks.Range("J5:J1048576") = ActiveSheet.Range("C12"))`.

Comment: How to replace this formula with its values using vba?

Comment: In fact, the error is bigger than I first said, this whole bit won't work: `(slWks.Range("J5:J1048576") = ActiveSheet.Range("C12")) * slWks.Range("D5:D1048576")`. I don't know whether @Rory is correct about the size being too large, but if he is then you will have to write your own function to do what you want, rather than using `SUMPRODUCT`. If your ranges don't actually need to be that large, you could loop through setting up an array containing the values in column `D` you want, and zeroes in places you don't want the values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two possible simple solutions, given that worksheetfunction methods won't work with arrays the size that you are using:

First, add the formula and then replace it with its value

```
With activesheet.Range("F12")
   .Formula =" =SUMPRODUCT((Sale!$J$5:$J$1048576=C12)*Sale!$D$5:$D$1048576,Sale!$M$5:$M$1048576)"
   .Value2 = .Value2
End With
```

Second, use `Evaluate`:

```
With Activesheet
   .range("F12").Value2 = .Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT((Sale!$J$5:$J$1048576=C12)*Sale!$D$5:$D$1048576,Sale!$M$5:$M$1048576)")
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking a guess at your use case:

- `C12` is some product you are interested in
- `Sale!$J$5:$J$1048576` is a range of products
- `(Sale!$J$5:$J$1048576=C12)` gives an array like `{1,1,1,0,0,0...}`
- `Sale!$D$5:$D$1048576` is a range of unit prices
- `Sale!$M$5:$M$1048576` is a range of number of units sold
- Your `SUMPRODUCT` gives a the revenue of for the product in `C12`

So for this sample data:

[image]

You could use this code to do leverage `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SumProductWithVBA()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strProduct As String
    Dim dblRevenue As Double
    Dim wsf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim v1 As Variant, v2 As Variant, v3 As Variant, v4 As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Set wsf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    ' condition for SUMPRODUCT
    strProduct = ws.Range("A1").Value

    ' get the values of the ranges
    v1 = wsf.Transpose(ws.Range("A4:A15").Value)
    v2 = wsf.Transpose(ws.Range("B4:B15").Value)
    v3 = wsf.Transpose(ws.Range("C4:C15").Value)

    ' make the array like {1,1,1,0,0,0...etc}
    ' this is the equivalent of the SUMPRODUCT((range=value)... bit
    ReDim v4(1 To UBound(v1))
    For i = 1 To UBound(v1)
        If v1(i) = strProduct Then
            v4(i) = 1
        Else
            v4(i) = 0
        End If
    Next i

    ' now do the SUMPRODUCT with all the arrays set-up    
    dblRevenue = wsf.SumProduct(v4, v2, v3)

    ' test the output    
    MsgBox dblRevenue

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with sumproduct function and after many experiments I solved my problem with this code:

```
Sub Test2()
  Dim WS As Worksheet
  Dim a, b, c, Criteria As Range
  Dim data1, data2, data3, crite As String
  Dim LasTRow As Long

  Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sale")
  LasTRow = WS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

  Set a = WS.Range("A5:A" & LasTRow)
  Set b = WS.Range("b5:b" & LasTRow)
  Set c = WS.Range("c5:c" & LasTRow)
  Set Criteria = WS.Range("A1")

  data1 = a.Address
  data2 = b.Address
  data3 = c.Address
  crite = Criteria.Address
  WS.Range("b1").Formula = "=sumproduct((" & data1 & " = " & crite & ") *( " & data2 & " ) * ( " & data3 & " ))"

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain what this does different than the code in the question?