# VBA - Index SumProduct with mis

Tags: vba, indexing, userform, sumproduct

I am new to VBA and am working on a userform at the moment that has 3 ComboBoxes that a user picks 1 item from each. The intent is for the code to look up the corresponding 4th value from the spreadsheet and return it to a textbox on the userform. Right now I'm getting a "Type Mismatch (Error 13):"

I have been fiddling with this for going on 3 days now. Some websites say the SumProduct function doesn't work in VBA, some say it does as long as you specify "WorkSheetFunction", and still some say you should instead use 'evaluate'.
Like in this post: 
[SUMPRODUCT Formula in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042040/sumproduct-formula-in-vba)
(I didn't have much luck using 'evaluate' but my syntax might have been off)

Anyway, I created a quick example to show what I am trying to do. If anyone can help it would be tremendously appreciated.
[worksheetdata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoaVp.png)

this is the code I have been trying:

```
Private Sub TestButton_Click()
textboxTesting.Text =    Application.WorkSheetFucntion.Index(Range("Thickness"), _
Application.WorkSheetFucntion.SumProduct((Range("Wood") = "Oak") _
* (Range("Metal") = "Copper") * (Range("Box") = "Red")), 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: I am not sure if `(Range("Metal") = "Copper") ` yields something that can be multiplied.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got that syntax from here: (scroll down about 2/3rd of the page)
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2012/04/26/using-multiple-criteria-in-excel-lookup-formulas/
I had success using the Index(Sumproduct) with (Range("Metal") = "Copper") in the excel worksheet. Maybe it doesn't translate well to VBA though?

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to write your own function, I believe the below is much more understandable:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim thickness

    thickness = FindThickness("oak", "copper", "red")

    MsgBox (thickness)
End Sub

Function FindThickness(wood As String, metal As String, box As String) As String

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("Wood")

    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value = wood _
        And cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = metal _
        And cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = box Then

            FindThickness = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
            Exit Function

        End If

    Next cell

End Function
```

Comment: This is awesome. I guess I was unaware that 'Index(Match) could have more than 2 criteria too. Thank you so much. It works perfect!

Comment: @Jjc1000 - you are very welcome, please accept as answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Odd thing is happening. It seems the code will work for any input of wood, but the metal has to be "copper" and the color has to be "red". If I use anything else, I get a Run-time error '1004 - Unable to get the index property of the Worksheet Function Class". Not sure what is going on.

Comment: Couldn't get the code posted by @Kevin to return anything other than something from the 1st row of data (even when i changed the look up items).
Currently trying this,  but  getting "Type Mismatch error".
    textReturn1.Text =
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheet4.Range("Return3"), _
    WorksheetFunction.Match(1, _
    (comboWood.Value = Sheet4.Range("Wood")) * _
    (comboMetal.Value = Sheet4.Range("Metal")) * _
    (comboFlag.Value = Sheet4.Range("Flag")), 0))
^ I based the above on what I found here:
 https://www.contextures.com/excellookupmultiplecriteriaindexmatch.html

Comment: @Jjc1000 - I tried something similar, and you will not be able to get that to work with the array syntax. You will either have to do something similar to what I show above, or assign the value to a cell in the spreadsheet. Is there anything wrong with the above method?