# SUMPRODUCT Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sumproduct

I'm trying to use SUMPRODUCT Formula in excel on a table that will always have a different number of lines.

I have the following table

[image]

And I also have the following formula on the sheet to extract the necessary information

I want to find the total amount depending on different criteria, which are listed under the heading Sale Type, Sale status, Network.

I've used the following formula in the cell D17

`=SUMPRODUCT(((A3:A6=A17)+(A3:A6=A18))*((B3:B6=C17)+(B3:B6=C18))*((C3:C6=B17)+(C3:C6=B18))*E3:E6)` to get the total amount of 300.

[image]

I've found this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042040/sumproduct-formula-in-vba) useful, however, it deals with a finite number of lines. But I used it to the best of my ability to deal with tables in which the number of lines changes.

This is my formula

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1")

lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

ws.Range("D17").Formula=((("A3:A" & lastrow = "Arbitrage")+("A3:A" & lastrow = "New Payment"))*(("B3:B" & lastrow = "1")+("B3:B" & lastrow = "2"))*(("C3:C" & lastrow = "Complete")+("C3:C" & lastrow = "Under Review"))*"E3:E" & lastrow)
```

However, when I try to do this I get execution error 13, specifically on the code that I wrote. Any help on what I can do to resolve it please?

Thanks

Comment: `SUMIFS` is a lot easier here.

Comment: When you say "table" do you mean a `listObject`, or a simple range in a sheet?

Comment: Should this not be `.FormulaArray`?

Comment: For the RTE13, I assume you have a value that cannot be multiplied and it's erroring because it doesn't fit the criteria of the existing dimension.  Have you tried splitting your formula to multiple lines to see which piece of the seven elements is giving the error?  E.g., `termA ="A3:A" & lastrow = "Arbitrage"` & `termB = "A3:A" & lastrow = "New Payment"`.

Comment: From your screenshot it looks like your are using a table - you can access this within your VBA via the `listobject`- there you can access the `listcolumns` by there names, eg. `ws.listobjects(1).listcolumns("Sale Type").DatabodyRange.address` which will make your life much easier building the formula. Within your example you already mixed columns B and C ...